# vue using the components when interpolating a string

Tags: vue.js

How to use the component when interpolating a string?

For example, I have a component that do something like this:

**Component-A**

```
<template>
  <div>{{someProp}}</div>
</template>
```

When I use that component in others components I pass someProp which is a vue-component and some plain text.

**Other component**

```
<component-A someProp="Some text and <component-B/>"/>
```

How do I prevent the text from being escaped? And instead of the "<component-B/>" the component was substituted?

Comment: Did you try passing component-B as separate prop and then work with it to return desired values from component-A ?

Comment: In my case, adding a new prop is not desirable

Comment: why not import compnent-B inside of component A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props can only be used to pass javascript values, such as strings, numbers, objects, arrays, things like that. In your example, `someProp` has the string value `Some text and <component-B/>`, so it will render literally `Some text and <component-B/>` in the template.

If you want to pass a *template fragment* (my own terminology), then you will need to use a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) instead of a prop:

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: '<span>Component A: <slot></slot></span>',
});

Vue.component('component-b', {
  template: '<strong>Component B</strong>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    Some text and <component-b></component-b>
  </component-a>
</div>
```